# Android Multiple events not firing

Tags: android

I have OnTouchListener and OnItemClickListener attached to ListView and for some reason OnTouchListener  is getting fired but it stops OnItemClickListener from firing ? Any suggesstion on how to go about this ?

Comment: Can you also give a bit more data regarding your use case?

Answer (score 0):

Your  `OnTouchListener`  has consumed the touch event.

From here:
[check on the return value ...](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)

If you don't wanna consume the event on  `OnTouchListener` ,  just return `false` on `onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)` as suggested by the above link.